# How do I paste a Shape into the notes page of a Powerpoint presentation in VBA?

Tags: vba, copy-paste, powerpoint

I am trying to use the following code to paste a copied shape into a note page, but the Paste commands fails with the error "The specified data type is unavailable". It works if the clipboard contains texts instead of a shape. Any help is appreciated

```
Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oShapes As Shapes

Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1).NotesPage.Item(1)
Set oShapes = oSlide.Shapes
oShapes.Paste
```

Comment: Before pasting, you'll need to copy something, the `.Paste` is coming right after what can be speicified as `Destination`. So try `oShapes.Copy Destination:= oSlide`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known bug in PPT 2007/2010 but is fixed in 2013. 
For 2007/2010 switch to the notes page view, move to the desired notes page and then use `ActiveWindow.View.Paste` to get the same effect.